# Unable to find Address views/.phtml files even with Template Path Hints

Tags: customer, adminhtml, magento-2.1, address

I need to be able to change this view (only very slightly to show the address ID)

[image]

The problem is, even with Admin Template Hints on I can't figure out where the relvant files are stored? Looking through the directory structure there isn't anything obvious either.

Has anyone else come across this? Is there another way of find out where these are?

Comment: Have you tried a `grep -iR "<some unique HTML identifier>" *` ?

Comment: @B00MER Yes I did, and it found nothing. I think it must be generate in JS some how :(